# running git on windows 8

Tags: git, windows-8

I'm using git on windows 8 and have problems moving files added to the source control. If the files are added on my computer when it's running windows 8, the files are not completely added. With that I mean that I can see the version history of the files with gitk, for example. But if I do a git-move, I get the answer that the file is not under version control and I can therefore not move the file. I have googled this issue and can't find anyone else having this problem. I only know that my colleague has the exact same problem. (I'm using git version 1.7.10.3)

Comment: Can you show the output of `git status` *before* doing the move, and then the exact commands you enter?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a trick with file name cases? For `git` `FileName.TXT` and `filename.txt` are two completly different files, while for Windows they are totally the same.

Please check the cases of the files you're working with on your disk and in the `git` index. See is there any difference in cases and then use file names used in `git` index as arguments to `git` commands.